# Please help me with the code to send a message to the channel

Tags: discord, discord.py, channel

I want the code to work what I wrote-test2 #chat and the bot sent a message there, but my code doesn't work. Please help me with the code and tell me where I made the mistake. I will be grateful!
My code:

```py
@client.command()
async def test2(ctx, name):
    chans = get(ctx.guild.channels, name = name)
    
    e = discord.Embed(title = f'hello')
    await chans.send(embed = e)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you print the `name` argument, you'll get something like this `<#771335478372204575>`, it's not a channel name, neither an ID

Top fix it you can use [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?#converters)

```py
@client.command()
async def test2(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    e = discord.Embed(title='hello')
    await channel.send(embed=e)
```